# Объект 'list' не имеет атрибута 'ndim'

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, numpy

Попробовал узнать разрешение изображений из массива images, используя **ndim**:

```
print(images.ndim)
```

Но выдало **ошибку**:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Пытался найти её в интернете, но там проблема с совершенно другой библиотекой и предлагают использовать np. `array()` , не отрицаю, что он мог бы помочь, да вот только я даже не знаю, куда именно его записать, пытался

```
images = np.array([[],[]])
```

Но из-за этого появлялась другая **ошибка**:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Массив images содержит загруженные таким образом изображения:

```
def load_data(data_directory):
directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory)
               if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
labels = np.array([[],[]])
images = np.array([[],[]])
for d in directories:
    label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
    file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f)
                  for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                  if f.endswith(".ppm")]
    for f in file_names:
        images.append(skimage.io.imread(f))
        labels.append(int(d))
```

Как можно исправить? Вопрос направлен к той ошибке, которую можно решить, ну а я, если честно, не знаю, которая из них решаема.

Comment: Можете показать, что вы присвоили к `images`, там где написали `print(images.ndim)`

Comment: Как была получена переменная images?

Comment: @Tehnorobot  добавил в вопросе.

Comment: `images` у вас обычный питоновский список, у него есть только длина `len(images)`. Кроме того, `ndim` - это количество измерений. Для двумерной картинки это 2. Что вам даст эта информация? Для того, чтобы посмотреть размер картинки нужно смотреть `.shape` у каждой конкретной картинки (а не у их списка).

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно присвоить к `images` список:
`images = []`  и также с `labels`.
В списках есть метод `append`, отвечающий за добавление элементов.
Если нужно узнать количество измерений с помощью `ndim`, то вот пример кода:

```
import numpy as np
 
lst = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

lst = np.append(lst, 0)

print(lst)

print(lst.ndim)
```

Пример реализации вывода разрешения изображений после применения `skimage.io.imread()`:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.array([[[235, 230, 234], [233, 228, 232]]]) # изображения 
print(lst[0, :,0:2]) # их разрешение
```

Но, все же, лучше использовать библиотеку PIL для получения разрешения изображения:

```
from PIL import Image

(img_width, img_height) = Image.open("имя изображения или путь к нему").size
```

Comment: Если я делаю таким образом, то выдается первая ошибка, указанная в вопросе, связанная с ndim.
А как мне можно применить метод append, чтобы ошибок не выдавало?

Comment: А зачем вам ndim?

Comment: @Techorobot , знакомлюсь с TensorFlow по гайду и надо научиться исследовать данные изображений, использую ndim и ещё один атрибут size, чтобы узнать разрешение и количество изображений.

Comment: @mlbl я дополнил кодом

Comment: Вы не так поняли, мне нужно узнать не количество измерений, а размерность изображения. И в целом в вашем коде так же выдает ошибку, связанную с атрибутом append.

Comment: Тогда вам не нужен ndim, для измерений изображения используйте библиотеку PIL

Comment: хорошо, посмотрю. Вообще в самом туториале использовался как раз таки ndim, но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: @mldl в `skimage.io.imread(f)` у вас будет список списков разрешения изображений. Здесь можно посмотреть в примере: https://question-it.com/questions/1174531/stroka-python-kak-fajl-v-skimage-imread. И с помощью ещё одного добавленого мной кода реализуйте ваше требование.

Comment: @mIbI размерность и есть количество измерений. А то, что вам нужно, называется размер.